# NUXT.JS plugin $plugin(...).catch() is not a function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, fetch-api, pinia

Im new to Nuxt and have a problem with fetch in a plugin. I've been looking in various tutorial and doc but wit no success. Seems that everything should be OK here.
This is the exact error:

`$apiFetch(...).catch is not a function`

So the question:
What can be wrong with this code?

Any help will be appreciated

I'm using in-built ofetch and writing a plugin based on it, to define baseUrl. Here is my plugin:

```
import {defineNuxtPlugin} from "#app";
import { ofetch } from "ofetch";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async nuxt => {

    const apiFetchCreated = await ofetch.create({
        baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
    });

    return {
        provide: {
            apiFetch: () => apiFetchCreated
        }
    }
})
```

For now this is being used an a Pinia store, in login function.

Check out the initialisation of the plugins inside the setup function of the store:
(I'm using Composition API for stores, and moreover, other plugins are working such as posthog)

```
    const { $posthog, $router, $apiFetch } = useNuxtApp()
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    const posthog = $posthog;
    const router = $router;
```

And the usage itself:

```
    async function login(email, password) {
        const {data} = await $apiFetch('auth/login', {
                method: "POST",
                body: {
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }
        }).catch(err => {
            loginMessage.value = err.response._data.message
            posthog.capture("User got Error on Login", {
                message:err.response._data.message
            })
        })

        posthog.capture("User Logged In")
        posthog.identify(userId, {
            email: email
        })

        proceedUserAfterAuth(data)

    }
```

File structure:

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMTj1.png)

I've tried setting it differently:

For example like that in the store:

```
    const { $posthog, $router, $apiFetch } = useNuxtApp()
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    const apiFetch = $apiFetch;
```